# Function to return negative values for numbers in an array

Tags: python

Using the following as an example:

```
PosList = [1,2,3,4,5]
NegList = [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]
```

If I want to get a positive value from numbers in an array I can do the following:

```
PosNum = [abs(i) for i in NegList]
PosNum
(Output)[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But if I want to do a similar task to return negative numbers from a positive list of numbers I am not aware of a standard function to do this.  I can do something like this:

```
minus = '-'
NegNum = [int(minus + str(i)) for i in PosList]
NegNum
(Output)[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
```

But surely there are much better ways of doing this task that I am overlooking...

Comment: `[-abs(i) for i in PosList]`?...

Comment: Why not just `-abs(i)`?

Comment: `[-i for i in PosList]`. Or `[-abs(i) for i in PosList]` if your starting numbers might not be positive.

Comment: @Delgan Do you want to add this as an answer for me to accept as you answered first? cheers

Comment: @adele I do not want to, but thank you for the proposal. Just keep in mind that you can use `-i` anywhere to reverse the sign of a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `-`ive sign before `abs()` as:

```
>>> PosList = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> NegList = [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]

# Negative values for `+`ive list
>>> [-abs(item) for item in PosList]
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]

# Negative values for `-`ive list
>>> [-abs(item) for item in NegList]
[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply negate the result of the abs function:

```
NegList = [-abs(i) for i in NegList]
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].